# Reshape np.array based on the default size

Tags: python, numpy, reshape, numpy-ndarray, valueerror

There are 2 np.arrays and I would like to reshape `np.array1` from shape `(12,)`in reference to `array2` with shape `(4,)`:

`array1 = np.array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12])` and 
`array1.shape`
returns: `(12,)`

`array2 = np.array([ 12,  34,  56,  78])`
and 
`array2.shape`
returns: `(4,)`

I tried to execute `reshape`:

`array1.reshape(array2.shape)`

But, there is an error:
`ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 12 into shape (4,)`

So, Expected result is `array1` with 4 elements: 
`np.array([ 1,  2,  3,  4])`, 
instead of 12.

I'd appreciate for any idea and help.

Comment: What happens to elements 5 through 12 after this "reshape"? Aren't you just truncating the array here?

Comment: @coldspeed, I need to select only first 4 elements from ```array1```. Yeah, I understand that  reshape and Truncate are two different operations. Truncate changes the size, but keeps the shape. Reshape keeps the size, but changes the shape. Finally, I have to use slicing. Thanks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, I think what you're looking for is simple slicing:

```
In [140]: array2 = np.array([ 12,  34,  56,  78])
In [135]: a_sliced =  array1[:array2.shape[0]]
In [136]: a_sliced.shape
Out[136]: (4,)
```

If `array2` is multi-dimensional, then use the [approach suggested by Mad Physicist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55581685/reshape-np-array-based-on-the-default-size/55581768?noredirect=1#comment97861906_55581768):

```
sliced_arr = array1[tuple(slice(0, d) for d in array2.shape)]
```

---

Alternatively, if you intended to split the array into three equal halves, then use [`numpy.split()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) as in:

```
# split `array1` into 3 portions
In [138]: np.split(array1, 3)
Out[138]: [array([1, 2, 3, 4]), array([5, 6, 7, 8]), array([ 9, 10, 11, 12])]
```

Comment: For the generalized case, `array1[tuple(slice(0, d) for d in array2.shape)]`

Comment: @kmario23, you understood question correctly. It works as expected. Thanks!

Comment: @Cindy great, :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist Although your approach is nice, I'm little hesitant to use a `for` loop where we can go without that!

Comment: @kmario23. I would only use that for cases where the number of dimensions can be arbitrary.